# c# remove all image in Excel using Epplus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have an excel sheet (ws) that has several pictures in it, and i want to removed all of it using EPPlus.

this is what i've done, and it worked, but I don't want to remove it using the title of the picture

```
ws.Drawings.Remove("Picture 1");
ws.Drawings.Remove("Picture 2");
```

is there a way to remove them all at once?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any method to remove them all with a single line of code, however you can do this by looping through all the drawings in a worksheet.

```
using (var p = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(@"c:\FooFolder\Foo.xlsx")))
{
    ExcelWorkbook wb = p.Workbook;
    ExcelWorksheet ew = wb.Worksheets.First();

    //get the number of drawings in the worksheet to loop through. 
    //Subtract 1 since the drawings use a 0 base index
    int drawingCount = ew.Drawings.Count -1;

    //loop through the drawings starting at highest number so the collections index doesn't change as you remove them
    for(int i = drawingCount; i>=0; i--)
    {
        //remove the drawing at current index
        ew.Drawings.Remove(i);
    }

    p.Save();            
}
```

Edit: After I posted this I found a much simpler method.
You can use `ExcelWorksheet.Drawings.Clear()` this method removes all drawings from the worksheet.

Comment: the ExcelWorksheet.Drawings.Clear() will clear everything like ExcelShape and not just ExcelPicture